Text is bound to object, but nothing is being displayed?
i have a binding on a text field as follows:
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="FontCamptonMedium" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding CurrentBooking.FullName}" TextColor="Black" />

in the code-behind of this page, we use dependency injection to bind to the corresponding view model, like so:
public AppointmentPendingResponse(BookingViewModel viewModel): base(viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel;
}

this view model that we are binding to inherits from another baseviewmodel, like this...
public partial class BookingViewModel : BaseViewModel

...which in turn, is declared like this:
public abstract partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable, INotifyPropertyChanged

in the baseviewmodel we implement the following to make use of inotifypropertychanged:
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
    Action onChanged = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
        return false;

    backingStore = value;
    onChanged?.Invoke();
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    var changed = PropertyChanged;
    if (changed == null)
        return;

    changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

inside the bookingviewmodel, we then populate the CurrentBooking property like this:
CurrentBooking = (BookingModel)selected;

the resulting json looks like this:
{\"FullName\":\"LAWMAN\",\"IdentityNo\":\"123\",\"Relation\":\"SELF\"}

the fact that i am able to get json data means CurrentBooking should not be null. so why is my label text not being populated? im not sure what im missing here.
Edit: ok, i changed the bookingmodel (the object type of CurrentBooking) to implement ObservableObject:
public partial class BookingModel: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private string _FullName;

and FullName still doesnt display.
Edit2: @klaus-gütter yes, here is an image:


Does the implementation of CurrentBooking use SetProperty in the setter? You can use the debugger to verify that executing the line CurrentBooking = (BookingModel)selected; actually raises the PropertyChanged event.

Why do you need INotifyPropertyChanged when you are already extending the ObservableObject class. The ObservableObject is a base class for objects that are observable by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyPropertyChanging interfaces  Please share your BookingViewModel code. You just need to make CurrentBooking as ObservableProperty

@PrabhavMehra all ObservableObject does is autogenerate the getters and setters, i have INotifyPropertyChanged because i have defined them myself manually. tried using both which is why u see them. originally was only using INotifyPropertyChanged

okay, i found the answer. this is so silly actually. the height of the containing border was so short that it actually cut off all the text im trying to display.
added the following and everything is good now:
HeightRequest="500"

woops 
